# SQL extra precision when calculating, why?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, precision

Do you know why SQL adds an extra precision when multiplying? example:

```
declare @x decimal(2,1) = 9.9;
Declare @y decimal(3,2) = 9.99;
--precision: p1 + p2 + 1 = 2 + 3 + 1 = 6
--scale:     s1 + s2 = 1 + 2 = 3
declare @rM decimal(5,3) = @x * @y;--this is OK, why is the resulting precision 6 if 5 is OK?
```

Is there a scenario I am not aware of where multiplying two values needs 6 for precision?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has [detailed documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Precision%20is%20the%20number%20of,decimal%20data%20types%20is%2038.) on the precision and scale of numeric with various arithmetic operations.

For multiplication, this is:

```
e1 * e2    precision:  p1 + p2 + 1    scale:  s1 + s2
```

I think these conform to rules derived from arithmetic.  The number of decimal places to the right of the decimal point is indeed `s1 + s2` -- remember, scale is the number to the right.  And I think the precision might be overstated by 1. 
 However, there might be some edge case where the extra decimal place is helpful.

Of course, the values are capped at the maximum scale and precision for a numeric/decimal value.